# Ran export TMPDIR=~/tmp/ and it broke my node app, can I revert the tmp folder to the default folder?

Tags: macos, mojave, catalina, environment-variables

Hey I ran `export TMPDIR=~/tmp/` and it changed my temp folder. I was trying to get a Go backend working and an article suggested it. I was a little trigger happy and now this is causing issues with a once working Node app I have.

The node app is now saying:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdtemp
>   '/Users/myName/tmp/puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-VYUdd3'

Is there a way to revert the temp var back and fix this problem. Where do env vars live on a mac. I also updated my mac from Mojave to Catalina during this process. Not sure if that has something to do with it too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`TMPDIR` needs to point to an existing, user-writable directory. So setting it to `~/tmp` is fine as long as `~/tmp` actually exists.

By default it points to `/var/folders/_d/_SOMERANDOMLOOKINGSTRING/T/` to ensure that every user has their private temp folder. If for whatever reason you loose the definition you can run `find /var/folders/_d -user $(whoami) -type d -maxdepth 1` to check that it still exists, and then do

```
export TMPDIR="$(find /var/folders/_d -user $(whoami) -type d -maxdepth 1)"
```

to set it back.

In case it doesn't exist any more (which is unlikely as it is protected by SIP), either reboot to have it recreated or run (all three lines)

```
export TMPDIR=/tmp
export TMPDIR="$(mktemp -d)"
chmod 700 "${TMPDIR}"
```

to create and assign a new temp folder.

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer. I ran `export TMPDIR=~/` to reset the TMPDIR to the root folder which has a tmp folder. You can check that the tmp folder is in the root by running `cd /` then `ls -a` to see the tmp directory you routed it to.

After resetting the temp to the mac's root directory all node applications ran as expected.

Comment: Exporting a variable just puts it in the current session.

Comment: Ah so restarting terminal would have resolved than too, most likely. Good to know, thanks for the help.

Comment: `TMPDIR=~/` sets it to your home folder, not the root folder. Both is wrong, actually, as TMPDIR is set to `/var/folders/_d/_SOMERANDOMLOOKINGSTRING/T/` or similar by default.